# Can't override bootstrap to implement my own CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

```
.lo:link, .lo:visited {
    color: #0060b6;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```
<div class="row">
      {% for project in projects %}
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <img src="{{ project.image.url }}" height="250" width="348">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4><a class="lo" href="{{ project.url }}">{{ project.title }}</a></h4>
            <p class="card-text">{{ project.description }}</p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

I'm trying to change the stuff in the `<a>` tag so it's not blue and highlighted.

CSS links are in the right order - bootstrap first, then my own.

I've also tried adding `!important` after each CSS property doesn't work.

I'm using the Django block content method to have header and footer but that shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: please post html and css

Comment: <div class="row">
      {% for project in projects %}
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <img src="{{ project.image.url }}" height="250" width="348">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4><a class="lo" href="{{ project.url }}" style="">{{ project.title }}</a></h4>
            <p class="card-text">{{ project.description }}</p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

Comment: .lo {
    color: #0060B6 !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

Comment: no edit your question with it.

Comment: When I took your code and put it in a fiddle with Bootstrap, the link color changed: https://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/g4e9Lh6z/2/ - that means some other code is overriding what you have.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **id** instead of **class**, because id has a higher priority than class:

```
#lo:link, #lo:visited {
  color: #0060b6;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: I don't really think it is a good practice to use IDs in stylesheets.

Comment: why?
I don't think so.
There are two different ways to change priorities
1)changing position between <link>  bootstrap tag in head and  customStyle.css
2)use id 
Do you know a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Override the property this way:

```css
.lo:link, .lo:visited {
    color: #0060b6;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: nah that didn't do it. I feel like my own css is just not coming through at all. I'll include my entire header see if that looks good. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap, `<a>` tag has its own rules which can be overridden easily.

```
a {
    color: #007bff; /* change to the color you want */ 
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}

a:hover {
    color: #0056b3; /* change me as you like */
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Also, I gave it a try using your style.And it did work for me in a new project which means, you need to check what's preventing it from changing? maybe it's about the `CSS specificity`

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! thanks, I really did try everything for 4 agonizing days, it turns out it was in settings.py (using django) STATIC_URL was set to a specific directory so I just had to put my custom css in there, reference that in html and it worked